# How to add line of select into div without their values in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have div that include some select boxes, I want to take this div and multiple without his select values.

```
<div class="line">
   <select name="someName">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2" selected>2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
   </select>

   <select name="someName2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3" selected>3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

The problem when I multiple he takes the values of the select box.

Edit:

```
<button type="button" click="addLineIntrsted" >Add</button>
```

Here is the jquery code that I am using to multiple the div:

```
var addLine = $('.line').first().html();
$('.addLineIntrsted').click(function(){
    $('.line').last().after('<div class="line">'+addLine+'</div>');
});
```

Comment: Can you give us what you have tried ? What multiplication are you talking about ?

Comment: Absolutely unclear what you are trying to ask here. I don’t see any “multiplication” going on anywhere, so what are you talking about …? Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by *take this div*?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove your selected options before:

`$('.line').children().find(':selected').remove();`

Btw: you may wanna change the "click" attribute to "class". Because youre selecting the button by its class: `$('.addLineIntrsted').click(...`

Comment: not working well, that delete all the select box, and also it clear the value from the select box that I copy.